# IDE like resizable split windows using html, css and js

Tags: javascript, html, css, panel

I am new to HTML and UI side. I want to create html page having left side horizontal and vertical bottom splitter like we get in vs code (IDE) using HTML, CSS and JS. Currently I am able to create the horizontal split but it is not accurate when I merge with bottom splitter.

I want to create html page having left side horizontal and vertical bottom splittee like we get in vs code (IDE) using HTML, CSS and JS. Currently I am able to create the horizontal split but it is not accurate when I merge with bottom splitter.

[image: image attached for reference]

```css
.splitter {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

#separator {
    cursor: col-resize;
    background-color: #aaa;
    background-position: center;
    width: 5px;
    height: 40rem;


    /* Prevent the browser's built-in drag from interfering */
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

#first {
    /* background-color: #dde; */
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 150px;
}

#second {
    /* background-color: #eee; */
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 750px;
}


  
  #h-separator {
    cursor: col-resize;
    background-color: #aaa;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    /* Prevent the browser's built-in drag from interfering */
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  #top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 10px;
    background-color:red;
  }
  
  #bottom {
    background-color: green;
    min-width: 10px;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px !important;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Page Layout</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
            <form class="form-inline">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Custom</button>
            </form>
        </nav>


        <div class="h-splitter">
            <div id="top">

                <div class="splitter">
                    <div id="first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore labore, placeat consequatur
                        culpa non nisi nam error eum? Reiciendis enim recusandae nostrum temporibus sit voluptatem distinctio dolore
                        repudiandae nesciunt explicabo.</div>
                    <div id="separator"></div>
                    <div id="second">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa ex praesentium ducimus cum
                        officiis tempora repudiandae dolorem, blanditiis ad doloribus nesciunt, laboriosam quos et rem facilis
                        quibusdam quisquam voluptatum enim?
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, saepe architecto, non, rerum iure est
                        corrupti quod a consectetur nobis animi illo dolor quaerat deserunt odio incidunt tempora nulla sequi!
                    </div>
                </div>



            </div>
            <div id="h-separator"></div>
            <div id="bottom"></div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    
        // A function is used for dragging and moving
        function dragElement(element, direction, VDirection)
        {
            console.log(direction);
            var   md; // remember mouse down info
            const first  = document.getElementById("first");
            const second = document.getElementById("second");
        
            element.onmousedown = onMouseDown;
        
            function onMouseDown(e)
            {
                md = {e,
                      offsetLeft:  element.offsetLeft,
                      offsetTop:   element.offsetTop,
                      firstWidth:  first.offsetWidth,
                      secondWidth: second.offsetWidth
                     };
        
                document.onmousemove = onMouseMove;
                document.onmouseup = () => {
                    console.log("mouse up");
                    document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
                }
            }
        
            function onMouseMove(e)
            {
                var delta = {x: e.clientX - md.e.clientX,
                             y: e.clientY - md.e.clientY};
        
                if (direction === "H" ) // Horizontal
                {
                    // Prevent negative-sized elements
                    delta.x = Math.min(Math.max(delta.x, -md.firstWidth),
                               md.secondWidth);
        
                    element.style.left = md.offsetLeft + delta.x + "px";
                    first.style.width = (md.firstWidth + delta.x) + "px";
                    second.style.width = (md.secondWidth - delta.x) + "px";
                }
            }
        }
        
        dragElement( document.getElementById("separator"), "H");
        

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        function dragVElement(element, direction) {
        var md; // remember mouse down info
        const first = document.getElementById("top");
        const second = document.getElementById("bottom");

        element.onmousedown = onMouseDown;

        function onMouseDown(e) {
            //console.log("mouse down: " + e.clientX);
            md = {
            e,
            offsetLeft: element.offsetLeft,
            offsetTop: element.offsetTop,
            firstHeight: first.offsetHeight,
            secondHeight: second.offsetHeight
            };

            document.onmousemove = onMouseMove;
            document.onmouseup = () => {
            //console.log("mouse up");
            document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
            }
        }

        function onMouseMove(e) {
            //console.log("mouse move: " + e.clientX);
            var delta = {
            x: e.clientX - md.e.clientX,
            y: e.clientY - md.e.clientY
            };

            if (direction === "V") // Vertical
            {        
            // Prevent negative-sized elements
            delta.x = Math.min(Math.max(delta.y, -md.firstHeight),
                md.secondHeight);

            element.style.top = md.offsetTop + delta.x + "px";
            first.style.height = (md.firstHeight + delta.x) + "px";
            second.style.height = (md.secondHeight - delta.x) + "px";
            }
        }
        }


        dragVElement(document.getElementById("h-separator"), "V");

        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by playing with `position`, `dynamic width`, and `display` properties.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 10vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: brown;
}

.section-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
}

.section-left {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.section-right {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(24, 99, 99);
}
```

```html
<div class="section section-top">
  <div class="section-left"></div>
  <div class="section-right"></div>
</div>
<div class="section section-footer"></div>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-wze5zm?file=index.html)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. These are static div. I want to create resizable (size of the div window must get change) from left to right (on sidebar ) and top to bottom(on bottom bar).